# Error trying to save a Python list to an S3 bucket.

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have tried my best to research this problem including on stack overflow and I just dont understand it. I just want to save the output of a Lambda function to an S3 bucket. But it seems like S3 doesnt like lists as a data type !?

I get an error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value:  type: <class 'list'>, valid
types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

It seems like a list is not a suitable output type for an S3 bucket? Here is the code I am using:

```
bucket_name = "output-bucket"
file_name = "output.json"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name)
object.put(Body=output_sentences)
```

I think I am just not understanding the way this works...

Comment: Can you add a sample `output_sentences` to your question? If it's a simple array of strings, you may consider serializing it to JSON before adding it to the object - `object.put(Body=json.dumps(output_sentences))`. Details about how you'll use that file would be helpful, too, for determining whether JSON is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

OK thanks. I managed to do it like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name)
object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(output_data, indent=2).encode('UTF-8'))))
```

Comment: You might want to change the `bytes(json.dumps(...))` info `pickle.dumps(json.dumps(...))` because `pickle` will serialize your object properly so you can read it back.

Comment: Pickle is very insecure--it opens up the opportunity for arbitrary code execution. Don't use it ever. It appears in tutorials all the time, and that is a great disservice.

Comment: I'm getting `Object of type Exception is not JSON serializable` error.

Answer (score 3):

If you (or anyone else who stumbles across this) didn't want to serialize to json and did want to write a list of strings to s3 as just a text file with newlines, like what you would get with a file and `.writelines()`, what you would do is

```
object.put(Body="\n".join(output_sentences))
```

or, if you prefer boto3's client api,

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.put_object(
    Body="\n".join(output_sentences),
    Key=file_name,
    Bucket=bucket_name,
)
```

S3 is happy to take a big string as the body of an object, if not a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

It says you can only store `bytes` or `bytearray`.

So you need to use `pickle` to convert your `list` into `bytes`.

```
import pickle

output_sentences = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']

# Convert your list to bytes
b = pickle.dumps(output_sentences)

# Save you object
object.put(Body=output_sentences)
```

Once you load your `byte` object again, you can transform back to a list with:

```
b = <load from S3>
read_sentence = pickle.loads(b)
```